# Puzzled by non-matching wire colors when installing a ceiling light

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, ceiling, light, rewire

I am trying to install a ceiling light that is using a 3 way switch. I have a single red wire coming from the ceiling box and a single white.   On the light fixture I have a single black and a single white.... what goes where.   I have attached a pic for reference. [image]

Comment: The wire near the middle right with the yellow nut on it looks like it might be a bare wire. In that case it's likely a ground wire and should be connected to both the metal of the ceiling box and to the green ground wire of your new fixture.

Comment: Yep. Got that part ready to go. It is the single red in the ceiling unit and the single black in my fixture that I need help with pls.

Comment: Normally the white wire is the neutral and gets connected to your light's white wire. Sometimes red is used instead of black as the switched "hot" power wire and in that case would be connected to the black "hot" wire of your light. This isn't posted as an answer because there are experts here on this (unlike me) who will likely post soon.

Comment: I did try connecting the black and red but the light would not work

Comment: Did the old light fixture work? How was it wired? Always good to take a pic before disconnecting anything.

Comment: We will have to wait for the expert posters. Did the previous light work fine with the same connections?

Comment: A 3 way has two switches. What color wires go to the second switch? Typically the red in the ceiling box would carry the switched hot but may not be true here. If you have a contactless tester you should be able to determine what's going on in the ceiling box. I'm assuming you haven't disconnected any wires at the switches.